# document.onkeydown not working, or working just once

Tags: javascript

So I have the following:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 119) {
        if (currentMode == 3) {
            currentMode = 0;
        } else {
            currentMode = currentMode++;
        }
        switchMode(currentMode);
    }
};
```

I've tried several combinations of `document`, `body` and `press/down/up`, and none seem to work. What's worse, the code (not this one, but a previous iteration) worked, until I removed a certain element. 
Now it either runs once then doesn't detect the keypresses anymore, or the keypresses are never even recognized to begin with.

I'll edit in a Fiddle with the whole page if necessary.

Comment: Maybe some error in `switchMode` function. Check console

Comment: "I'll edit in a Fiddle with the whole page if necessary." --- it is, not the whole page but the smallest possible piece that is sufficient to demonstrate the problem (usually during the narrowing operation you find the problem yourself)

Comment: If `document.onkeydown = function (e) {
 e = e || window.event;
 console.log(e);
};` works then `document.onkeydown` works! Need to debug other part of your code..

Comment: Where is `currentMode` being initialized?

Comment: No errors in the console whatsoever. It doesn't even get into the function sometimes. Just now I tried and it didn't work. Reloaded, and it did (for just one press though).

Comment: Marc Aduet, at the very top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a correct increment:

```
currentMode = currentMode++;
```

Your `currentMode` will never increase, because it will assign the same value.

Change it to:

```
currentMode++;
```

And it will work (`keyCode` 119 is <kbd>F8</kbd>):

```js
var currentMode = 0;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 119) {
        if (currentMode == 3) {
            currentMode = 0;
        } else {
            currentMode++;
        }
        switchMode(currentMode);
    }
};

function switchMode(mode) {
    document.getElementById('mode').innerText = mode;
}
```

```html
Current mode: <span id="mode">0</span>
```

Comment: Ahhh, I can't believe I could overlook such a thing. Well, now when it _does_ work, it works all the times, not just once. But there's still times when it doesn't work.

Comment: @730 What do you mean? This event fires everytime. Show the expected result.

Comment: I think I got it. My page is entirely composed of iframes, so when i click anywhere it actually loses focus from the document. Any way I can prevent this? Edit: guess I could add a handler for all iframes...

Comment: I ended up scrapping the key presses and going back to the <select> I had gone with at first to execute the needed function.

Comment: @730 Nice to hear it :)